# RVIZ Message Filter Queue Size

Tags: ros, rviz, queue, topic-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a setup where my pose information is greatly delayed ~0.5s from my PointCloud data.  Because of this, my TF timestamps lag behind by about the same 0.5s.

When I attempt to visualize this in RVIZ, the queue size is only 10 messages.  Since my laser data publishes much faster than that, I drop 100% of message since I would need a queue of ~40 messages to receive enough messages to transform them successfully.

Does RVIZ have a parameter. config, or setting for changing the MessageFilters queue size?

Also, if I use [topic tools throttle](http://www.ros.org/wiki/topic_tools/throttle), I can reduce the rate of incoming messages, prevent the queue from filling up, and then display around 5 to 10 messages per second.  This isn't an ideal work around though.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11701/rviz-message-filter-queue-size/) by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4541 on 2011-10-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hmmm, I got luckier with Googling, and I found this response:
http://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20100726.173011.b343a0f5.gl.html

And there's the hardcoded value of 10 in PointCloud2 display on line 51.
http://www.ros.org/doc/electric/api/rviz/html/point__cloud2__display_8cpp_source.html

Is there a way to change this dynamically or should I recompile RVIZ/make my own plugin?

If there isn't a way to change this, let me know, and I'll file a ticket.

---

[Filed ticket](http://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5227)

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2011-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-26**:
This definitely looks like a good enhancement ticket for rviz.